# Protect cells from having data pasted into them, but allow manual entry of new data

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Is it possible to protect a range of cells, so that a user can still type into them, but they cannot paste other cells over the top ?

I have been through all the 'Protect Sheet' options, 'Protect Workbook' and 'Allow Users to Edit Ranges' and none of these give me the ability to prevent cells being pasted into my range, without also preventing a user from being able to type new values.

Any suggestions? 
perhaps with vba using worksheet change ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no standard feature in Excel that does this.
You will need to write a VBA macro that detects paste to these cells and
cancels the operation.

You may get some inspiration from
[this article](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4289-excel-disable-cut-copy-paste.html).

Just to remark that asking us to write this VBA code will not work,
since the purpose of our site is not code-writing, only for general advice.